# How to execute javascript function with the pre-put string from database

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to run a javascript function with the pre loaded text from database. This function is about to display the image from youtube. Once a pasted link is correct. It will show the thumbnail automatically.

But I want a picture to display with the pre-text link from a database.

Here is the function :

```
function youtube_parser(url) {
    var regExp = /.*(?:youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/;
    var match = url.match(regExp);
    if (match && match[1].length == 11) {
        urllink = match[1];
        imagelink = "<img src=\"http:\/\/img.youtube.com\/vi\/"+urllink+"\/hqdefault.jpg\">";
    } else {
        //urllink = "test"
    }
    document.getElementById("ytimagelink").value = urllink;
    document.getElementById("ytimage").innerHTML = imagelink;       
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div><strong>Insert YouTube url:</strong></div>
<input type="text" id="ytlink" onkeyup="youtube_parser(this.value)">
    <hr>
    <div><strong>Output: YouTube video id:</strong></div>
    <input type="text" id="ytimagelink" value="">
        <div><strong>Output: Thumbnail</strong></div>
        <div id="ytimage"></div>
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/PMrLR/7/

This function will work as I put the url in `#ytlink` because there is a `onKeyUp` property to trigger the function.

So, I expect this function to work with the pre-loaded text without doing anything to it again.

Answer (score 0):

Your function will work as it is, just give it the text you loaded from the database as it's argument:

```
// ...get data from the database somehow, and then:
youtube_parser(url_from_database);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to wait for the document to load first, and then call the `youtube_parser(yourUrl)`. Do it like this in VanillaJS

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
   youtube_parser('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OnXTf8FNUrc');
});
```

Here is the snippet for you, show it and click run button

```js
function youtube_parser(url) {
  var regExp = /.*(?:youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/;
  var match = url.match(regExp);
  if (match && match[1].length == 11) {
    urllink = match[1];
    imagelink = "<img src=\"http:\/\/img.youtube.com\/vi\/" + urllink + "\/hqdefault.jpg\">";
  } else {
    //urllink = "test"
  }
  document.getElementById("ytimagelink").value = urllink;
  document.getElementById("ytimage").innerHTML = imagelink;
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  youtube_parser('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OnXTf8FNUrc');
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div><strong>Insert YouTube url:</strong>
</div>
<input type="text" id="ytlink" onkeyup="youtube_parser(this.value)">
<hr>
<div><strong>Output: YouTube video id:</strong>
</div>
<input type="text" id="ytimagelink" value="">
<div><strong>Output: Thumbnail</strong>
</div>
<div id="ytimage"></div>
```